# Adding header in GitHub API request in React

Tags: github-api, github-api-v3

I am using GitHub API to fetch file from repo:

```js
const octokit = new Octokit({
auth: "*******************************",
});

const response = await octokit.request(
  "GET /repos/owner/repo/contents/path",
  {
    owner: "owner",
    repo: "repo",
    path: "path",
  }
);
```

but I am getting response in base64 format.
I need to add header `Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw`.
Is there a way to add headers in Octokit request?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js#media-type-previews-and-formats

Answer (score 0):

You can register custom endpoint methods such as `octokit.rest.repos.get()` using the `octokit.registerEndpoints(routes)` method

```js
octokit.registerEndpoints({
  foo: {
    bar: {
      method: "GET",
      url: "/repos/{owner}/{repo}/foo",
      headers: {
        accept: "application/vnd.github.VERSION+raw",
      },
      params: {
        ...
      },
    },
  },
});

octokit.foo.bar({
  owner: "octokit",
  repo: "rest.js",
  baz: "quz",
});
```

view more here
[Register Custom endpoint | octokit/rest.js documentation](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#:%7E:text=You%20can%20register%20custom%20endpoint%20methods%20such%20as%20octokit.rest.repos.get()%20using%20the%20octokit.registerEndpoints(routes)%20method)

Comment: I am already using octokit for another upload function, so not able to use octokit rest for this purpose.